# How do I pass gesture data to parent view and why do all my images drag together?

Tags: swiftui, drag-and-drop, gesture

I am just a hobbyist trying to learn swiftui so I may not be even asking the right questions but here is the view I created to build a basic square grid that could be used for checkers. It works exactly as I would like but now I'm trying to add gestures.

Issue 1: On the main VStack under the .onTapGesture the "if x != nil { print(x!) } " correctly prints out the square that was tapped on.  How do I get that info back to the view that called it or get it to change data in my Model to register the selection and/or trigger the event to highlight the square? This struct is in its own file. Do I have to put this entire struct inside my main struct for this to work? I feel like I'm missing something conceptually. I can trigger the highlight from subviews that are part of the bigger view with a button but can't figure out what the approach is for "generic views" outside the main struct.

Issue 2: it seems to lump all of the imageItems together for the .gesture(dragGesture). I can only drag by clicking the last item in the grid and as I move it around, all imageItems move as one. I feel like I read a stack overflow that addressed this before but can't find it now.

PS if you just feel like teaching a little, lol, any changes you would recommend?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FixedSquareGrid<Item: Identifiable, ItemView: View>: View {
    let lightSquare: String
    let darkSquare: String
    
    @State private var translation = CGSize.zero
    @State private var lastTranslation = CGSize.zero

    var items: [Item]
    @ViewBuilder var content: (Item) -> ItemView
    
    init(_ items: [Item], lightSquare: String, darkSquare: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> ItemView) {
        self.items = items
        self.content = content
        self.lightSquare = lightSquare
        self.darkSquare = darkSquare
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let numberOfRows: Int = Int(sqrt(Double(items.count)))
            let gridItemSize = gridItemWidthThatFits(
                count: numberOfRows,
                size: geo.size)
            let boardSize = maxBoardSize(
                boardSquaresSize: gridItemSize * CGFloat(numberOfRows),
                size: geo.size)
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach (0..<numberOfRows, id: \.self) { row in
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach (0..<numberOfRows, id: \.self) { col in
                            let itemImage = content(items[((row * numberOfRows) + col)])
                            ZStack {
                                Image(((row % 2) + col) % 2 == 0 ? lightSquare : darkSquare)
                                    .padding(0)
                                    .frame(width: gridItemSize , height: gridItemSize)
                                    .clipped()
                                itemImage
                                    .padding(.bottom, 1)
                                    .frame(width: gridItemSize, height: gridItemSize)
                                    .clipped()
                                    .gesture(dragGesture)
                                    .offset(
                                        x: lastTranslation.width + translation.width,
                                        y: lastTranslation.height + translation.height
                                    )
                           }
                            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: boardSize + 10, height: boardSize + 10 )
            .background(Color.black)
            .onTapGesture( perform: { location in
                let x = squareTapped(clickedAt: location, itemSize: gridItemSize, rowCount: numberOfRows)
                if x != nil { print(x!) }
            })
        }.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
    func maxBoardSize(boardSquaresSize: CGFloat, size: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
        let maxSquareSpace = (size.width <= size.height ? size.width : size.height)
        return (maxSquareSpace <= boardSquaresSize ? maxSquareSpace : boardSquaresSize)
    }
                
    func gridItemWidthThatFits(
        count: Int,
        size: CGSize
    ) -> CGFloat {
        let rowCount = CGFloat(count)
        let width = (size.width / rowCount)
        let height = (size.height / rowCount)
        return (width <= height ? width : height).rounded(.down)
    }
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                translation = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                lastTranslation.width += value.translation.width
                lastTranslation.height += value.translation.height
                translation = .zero
            }
    }

    func squareTapped(clickedAt: CGPoint, itemSize: CGFloat, rowCount: Int) -> Int? {
        let col = Int((clickedAt.x / itemSize).rounded(.down))
        let row = Int((clickedAt.y / itemSize).rounded(.down))
        let sqr = col + (rowCount * row)
        let inBoundsSquare: Int? = (sqr > 0 && sqr <= (rowCount * rowCount) - 1 ) ? sqr : nil
        return inBoundsSquare
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FixedSquareGrid` can just take an extra `(Item) -> Void` function so that super views can detect that an item is tapped.

```
let items: [Item]
@ViewBuilder var content: (Item) -> ItemView
let itemTapped: (Item) -> Void // extra property here

init(
    _ items: [Item],
    lightSquare: String,
    darkSquare: String,
    @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Item) -> ItemView,
    itemTapped: @escaping (Item) -> Void // extra argument here
) {
    self.items = items
    self.content = content
    self.itemTapped = itemTapped
    self.lightSquare = lightSquare
    self.darkSquare = darkSquare
}
```

Then you can call this in `onTapGesture`:

```
.onTapGesture() { location in
    if let index = squareTapped(clickedAt: location, itemSize: gridItemSize, rowCount: numberOfRows) {
        itemTapped(items[index])
    }
}
```

Usage would look something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        FixedSquareGrid(
            [ /* insert your items here */ ],
            lightSquare: "...", darkSquare: "..."
        ) { item in
            // ...
        } itemTapped: { item in
            // handle tap here...
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider putting the tap gesture on each of the `ZStack`s, so that you don't have to calculate which square is tapped using the `squareTapped` method.

---

As for the drag gesture, you only declared one set of states (`translation` and `lastTranslation`) for all the grid items, so of course they all move together.

Each draggable thing should have its own pair of `translation` and `lastTranslation` states. You can make a new `View` or `ViewModifier` that contains these states.

```
// the way you implemented the drag gesture is kind of weird
// I changed it to an implementation similar to the one here:
// https://sarunw.com/posts/move-view-around-with-drag-gesture-in-swiftui/
struct DraggableModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @GestureState private var startOffset: CGSize? = nil
    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                var newOffset = startOffset ?? offset
                newOffset.width += value.translation.width
                newOffset.height += value.translation.height
                self.offset = newOffset
            }.updating($startOffset) { (value, startOffset, transaction) in
                startOffset = startOffset ?? offset
            }
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .offset(offset)
            .gesture(drag)
    }
}
```

```
itemImage
    .padding(.bottom, 1)
    .frame(width: gridItemSize, height: gridItemSize)
    .clipped()
    .modifier(DraggableModifier())
```

Comment: I understand conceptually. This is great.  I’ll have tackle actually implementing it tomorrow lol. I appreciate all the time you gave to this answer.  Thanks so much!